# What's the Protocol around Answering Your Own Question?

Tags: discussion, answers

I posted a question on StackExchange, but still required assistance from Ellis Lab. They provided me with a solution, that may work for others but doesn't work for me. I posted that solution, but I'm uncertain if I should 'accept' my own answer to a question. Is that a no-no or perfectly fine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely OK to answer your own question and then accept your own answer. If none of the answers have a solution to your particular question then I'd say it's *preferable* to post your own answer and accept it. That way future users encountering your post can benefit and will know that the question is in a more-resolved state.

There are a few rules in place to discourage abuse of this feature:

- You have to wait 48 hours before you can accept your own answer
- No reputation is earned for the accept.
- A self-accepted answer will not be pinned to the top as (unlike a "normal" accepted answer which is anchored to the top of the list regardless of whether it has the most upvotes).

Comment: Thanks Alex, what I needed to know.